# Filter dataset so only programs appear which were organised sooner

Tags: r, filter

Imagine the following dataset (tabel = DT)

```
ID    Program   Year
ABC   xxx       2000
ABC   yyy       2001
ABC   zzz       2002
DEF   xxx       2000
DEF   zzz       2001
DEF   yyy       2002
```

I want to filter the table so only programs appear PER UNIQUE ID which were organised sooner or in the same year as the selected program (e.g. selection = yyy)

In this case - when selecting the program yyy - this would give the following output

```
ID    Program   Year
ABC   xxx       2000
ABC   yyy       2001
DEF   xxx       2000
DEF   zzz       2001
DEF   yyy       2002
```

Does anyone have an idea on an R-code to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can `group_by` `ID` and find the index where `Program == "yyy"` get the corresponding `Year` and `filter` the rows which have `Year` less than the extracted one.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Year <= Year[which.max(Program == "yyy")])


#  ID    Program  Year
#  <fct> <fct>   <int>
#1 ABC   xxx      2000
#2 ABC   yyy      2001
#3 DEF   xxx      2000
#4 DEF   zzz      2001
#5 DEF   yyy      2002
```

Comment: Maybe even `df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 filter(Year <= Year[Program == "yyy"])`?

Comment: @tmfmnk Yes, for this example it will work when you have only one `yyy` per `ID`, It may give incorrect results  if there are more than 1 `yyy` per `ID`. `which.max` allows selection of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `slice` after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   slice(which(Year <= Year[match("yyy", Program)]))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
#  ID    Program  Year
#  <chr> <chr>   <int>
#1 ABC   xxx      2000
#2 ABC   yyy      2001
#3 DEF   xxx      2000
#4 DEF   zzz      2001
#5 DEF   yyy      2002
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[Year <= Year[match("yyy", Program)]], ID]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF"
), Program = c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "xxx", "zzz", "yyy"), Year = c(2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```